# How should Amazon SQS be used? Import / Process Scenario

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I want to co-ordinate telling Server B to start a process from Server A, and then when its complete, run an import script on Server A. I'm having a hard time working out how I should be using SQS correctly in this scenario.

Server A: Main Dedicated Server
Server B: Cloud Process Server

- Server A sends message to SQS via SNS to say "Start Process"
- Server B constantly polls SQS for "Start Process" message
- Server B finds "Start Process" message on SQS
- Server B runs "process.sh" file
- Server B completes running "process.sh" file
- Server B removes "Start Process" from SQS
- Server B sends message to SQS via SNS to say "Start Import"
- Server A polls constantly polls SQS for "Start Import" message
- Server A finds "Start Import" message on SQS
- Server A runs import.sh
- Server A completes running "import.sh"
- Server A removes "Start Import" from SQS

Is this how SQS should be used or am I missing the point completely?

Comment: Why would you need SNS here?

Also, "constant polling" became much better recently, as you can use long polling, that is specify that the SQS server should wait for max 20 seconds if there are no messages in the queue.

This way you'll only need to make one request each 20 seconds, if there are no messages.

Comment: @adamw I thought SNS could be a reliable way to add messages to the queue. Is it not needed then?

Comment: @adamw like this: http://forecastcloudy.net/2011/07/12/using-amazons-simple-notification-service-sns-and-simple-queue-service-sqs-for-a-reliable-push-processing-of-queues/

Comment: Ah, that way you could avoid polling. Depends on the use-case of course, but maybe the long-polling will be enough.

However, the whole point of using SNS here is different: you don't have to constantly poll the queue. Instead, SNS does two things - puts a message to the queue *and* notifies server B that it should check the queue. Otherwise you don't need SNS.

Comment: @adamw So I can skip SNS, and simply use SQS with long polling and add messages to the que directly via SQS, not SNS?

Comment: Yes, I don't see a reason why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you laid out will work in theory, but I am moved away from putting messages directly into queues, and instead put those messages in to SNS topics, and then subscribe the queues to the topics to get them there - gives you more flexibility to change things down the road without every touching the code or the servers that are in production.

For the what you are doing now, the SNS piece is unnecessary, but using will allow you to change functionality without touching you existing servers down the road.

For example: needs change and you want to add a process C that also kicks off every time the 'Start Process' runs on Sever B. Right thru the AWS SNS console you could direct a second copy of the message to another Queue that previously did not exist, and setup a server C that polls from that Queue (a fan out pattern).

Also, what I often like to do during initial rollout is add notifications to SNS so I know whats going on, i.e. every time the 'start process' event occurs, I subscribe my cell phone (or email address) to the topic so I get notified - I can monitor in real time what is (or isn't) happening. Once a period of time has gone by after a production deployment, I can go into AWS console and simply unsubscribe my email/cell from the process - without every touching any servers or code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm almost sorry that Amazon offers SQS as a service. It is not a "simple queue", and probably not the best choice in your case. Specifically:

- it has abysmal performance in low volume messaging (some messages will take 90 seconds to arrive)
- message order is not preserved
- it is fond of delivering messages more than once
- they charge you for polling

The good news is it scales well. But guess what, you don't have a scale problem, so dealing with the quirky behavior of SQS is just going to cause you pain for no good reason. I highly recommend you check out RabbitMQ, it is going to behave exactly like you want a simple queue to behave.

Comment: This is certainly not my experience with SQS. I got great performance and with the latest updates, polling is easy as well.

Comment: Not my experience as well. We're using SQS in several projects, without any problems.

Comment: Perhaps the latest updates have improved performance, good. But what about out of order messages and duplicate messages? Those are part of SQS by design, I don't think that is ever going to change.

Comment: @Jeff, yes, that's true, that's by design, "it's a feature, not a bug". Depends what you need in your app ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well... SQS doesn't not support message routing, in order to assign message to server A or B that why one of the available solutions: create SNS topics "server a" and "server b". These topics should put messages to SQS, which your application will pull. Also it possible to implement web hook - the subscriber on SNS events which will analyze message and do callback to your application.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So I should create a SNS topic for each server. For example ServerA will have its only topic "ServerA" and then this SNS system can be used to create SQS queues which can run tasks?

Comment: Yes, it's my idea how to make message broker for message routing. You can not use SNS - it just additional layer, which can help you, for instance, replace SQS to call of REST API or add web hook, which will do callbacks to your application.